# how send data with formData by mutilevel model in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I fill this model in service and need to send that to server :

```js
    export interface AddAlbumeModel {
        name: string;
        gener: string;
        signer: string;
        albumeProfile:any;
        albumPoster:any;
        tracks:TrackMode[];
    }
    
    export interface TrackMode {
        trackNumber: number;
        trackName: string;
        trackProfile: any;
        trackPoster:any;
        trackFile: any;
    }
```

and this data of model :

```js
    albumPoster: File {name: "One Kiss - CALVIN HARRIS ft DUA LIPA.mp3", lastModified: 1594883323701, lastModifiedDate: Thu Jul 16 2020 11:38:43 GMT+0430 (Iran Daylight Time), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 8628224, …}
    albumeProfile: File {name: "One Kiss - CALVIN HARRIS ft DUA LIPA.mp3", lastModified: 1594883323701, lastModifiedDate: Thu Jul 16 2020 11:38:43 GMT+0430 (Iran Daylight Time), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 8628224, …}
    gener: "5f0881d642b526384cf5afe4"
    name: "a"
    signer: "5f0af9983c432f0ebcdc8799"
    tracks: Array(2)
    0:
          trackFile: File {name: "One Kiss - CALVIN HARRIS ft DUA LIPA.mp3", lastModified: 1594883323701, lastModifiedDate: Thu Jul 16 2020 11:38:43 GMT+0430 (Iran Daylight Time), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 8628224, …}
          trackName: "a"
          trackNumber: 1
          trackPoster: File {name: "One Kiss - CALVIN HARRIS ft DUA LIPA.mp3", lastModified: 1594883323701, lastModifiedDate: Thu Jul 16 2020 11:38:43 GMT+0430 (Iran Daylight Time), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 8628224, …}
          trackProfile: File {name: "One Kiss - CALVIN HARRIS ft DUA LIPA.mp3", lastModified: 1594883323701, lastModifiedDate: Thu Jul 16 2020 11:38:43 GMT+0430 (Iran Daylight Time), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 8628224, …}
    1:
          trackFile: File {name: "One Kiss - CALVIN HARRIS ft DUA LIPA.mp3", lastModified: 1594883323701, lastModifiedDate: Thu Jul 16 2020 11:38:43 GMT+0430 (Iran Daylight Time), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 8628224, …}
          trackName: "1"
          trackNumber: 1
          trackPoster: File {name: "One Kiss - CALVIN HARRIS ft DUA LIPA.mp3", lastModified: 1594883323701, lastModifiedDate: Thu Jul 16 2020 11:38:43 GMT+0430 (Iran Daylight Time), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 8628224, …}
          trackProfile: File {name: "One Kiss - CALVIN HARRIS ft DUA LIPA.mp3", lastModified: 1594883323701, lastModifiedDate: Thu Jul 16 2020 11:38:43 GMT+0430 (Iran Daylight Time), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 8628224, …}


no i want to send this model to server by this format :

    albumPoster: (binary)
    albumeProfile: (binary)
    gener: 5f0881d642b526384cf5afe4
    name: a
    signer: 5f0af9983c432f0ebcdc8799
    tracks : [ 
          {
              trackFile: (binary)
              trackNumber: 1
              trackName: a
              trackPoster: (binary)
              trackProfile: (binary)},
          {
              trackFile: (binary)
              trackNumber: 1
              trackName: 1
              trackPoster: (binary)
              trackProfile: (binary)
           }
         ]

but it send data to server by this format :


    albumPoster: (binary)
    albumeProfile: (binary)
    gener: 5f0881d642b526384cf5afe4
    name: a
    signer: 5f0af9983c432f0ebcdc8799
    trackFile: (binary)
    trackNumber: 1
    trackName: a
    trackPoster: (binary)
    trackProfile: (binary)
    trackFile: (binary)
    trackNumber: 1
    trackName: 1
    trackPoster: (binary)
    trackProfile: (binary)

and i tyy to convert model to form data by this way . but its not worked :

     Create(item: AddAlbumeModel, url: string): Observable<any> {
        console.log(item)
        const Url = `${this.appConfig.apiEndpoint + url}`;
        const formData: FormData = new FormData();
        for (const key in item) {
            if (item.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                if (key === 'tracks') {
                    item.tracks.forEach(element => {
                        for (const keyb in element) {
                            if (element.hasOwnProperty(keyb)) {
                                if (element[keyb] instanceof File) {
                                    formData.append(keyb, element[keyb], element[keyb].name);
                                } else {
                                    formData.append(keyb, element[keyb]);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    })
                }
                else {

                    if (item[key] instanceof File) {
                        formData.append(key, item[key], item[key].name);
                    } else {
                        formData.append(key, item[key]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return this.httpClient
            .post(Url, formData, {
                headers: this.headers,
                reportProgress: true,
                observe: 'events'
            })
            .pipe(map(response => response || {} as HttpEvent<any>));
    }
```

**now my problem is here , i want to send data with formData to server by multi level in angular but it send data in one level . how can i solve this problem ???????**

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is when you are looping it's having always the same key, so it's actually overriding the same key.

So in order it to work you need to loop and add beside each element the index of the element for example:
Formdata.appened('tracks.${keyb}[${index}]')